# Extracting and cbinding similarly named variables in a data.frame in R

Tags: r, list, function, loops, dataframe

I have a `cbind` of 2 `data.frames` called `DATA`. Using **BASE R**, I was wondering how I could extract and then, `cbind` similarly named variables in `DATA` and store them as a list?

For the example below, I want all variable `AA`s, and separately all variable `BB`s in `DATA` be separately `cbind`ed and stored as a list?

***Note:*** names could be anything, and the number of variables could be any number. A function(al) solution is highly appreciated.

**Note:** suppose we have NO ACCESS to `r`, the only input is `DATA`.

```
r <- list(
 data.frame(Name = rep("Jacob", 6), 
           X = c(2,2,1,1,NA, NA), 
           Y = c(1,1,1,2,1,NA), 
           Z = rep(3, 6), 
         out = rep(1, 6)), 

 data.frame(Name = rep("Jon", 6), 
           X = c(1,NA,3,1,NA,NA), 
           Y = c(1,1,1,2,NA,NA), 
           Z = rep(2, 6), 
         out = rep(1, 6)), 

 data.frame(Name = rep("Jon", 6), 
            X = c(1,NA,3,1,NA,NA), 
            Y = c(1,1,1,2,2,NA), 
            Z = rep(2, 6), 
          out = rep(2, 6)), 

 data.frame(Name = rep("Jim", 6), 
            X = c(1,NA,3,1,NA,NA), 
            Y = c(1,1,1,2,2,NA), 
            Z = rep(2, 6), 
          out = rep(1, 6)))

DATA <- do.call(cbind, r)  ## DATA: cbind of two data.frames
```

Comment: @RonakShah, the problem is how to capture the common colnames in DATA. Arun, suggests using: `tbl <- table(names(DATA));
nm1 <- names(which(tbl==max(tbl)))`. But this strategy fails for example if DATA is like: `r <- list( data.frame( AA = c(2,2,1,1,3,2), BB = c(1,1,1,2,2,NA), CC = 1:6), data.frame( AA = c(1,NA,3,1,3,2), BB = c(1,1,1,2,2,2)), data.frame( CC = c(1,NA,3,1,3,2), AA = c(1,1,1,2,2,2), BB = 0:5) ); DATA <- do.call(cbind, r)`.

Comment: @akrun, Arun, [*my question there*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58309964/separate-columns-with-constant-numbers-and-condense-them-to-one-row-in-r-data-fr/58310137#58310137) is related to your answer here. Suppose we want to condense variables that are constant after the `lapply` call below. How can we do that here?

Comment: @Reza  is that not the answer you want

Comment: @Reza I updated the post.  May be I thought differently

Comment: @Reza please do ask another question if you need more clarification

Comment: @akrun, suppose I want to apply your `aggregate(.~ study.name, r, head, 1, na.action = NULL)` solution to the output of your `lapply` to condense variables that are constant. How could I do that `aggregate(.~ study.name, L, head, 1, na.action = NULL)` won't work?

Comment: @Reza I updated the post.  Please check

Comment: @akrun, posted my new question [**HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58311736/follow-up-separate-columns-with-constant-numbers-and-condense-them-to-one-row-i)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option with `split`.  Wouldn't recommend to have same duplicate column names in the dataset.  But, if it is really needed, after thee `split`, change the column names by removing the `.` following by one or more numbers at the end of it with `sub`

```
nm1 <- Reduce(intersect, lapply(r, colnames)) # get the common names
lst1 <- split.default(DATA[names(DATA) %in% nm1], names(DATA)[names(DATA) %in% nm1])
lapply(lst1, function(x) setNames(x, sub("\\.\\d+$", "", names(x))))
```

---

Or if we need to use only 'DATA' and not 'r' for finding the `intersec`ting column names.  It is difficult but we can get a frequency of the occurence of column names and select that have 2 as frequency

```
tbl <- table(names(DATA))
nm1 <- names(which(tbl==max(tbl)))
```

Use that in the `split.default` as before

```
lst1 <- split.default(DATA[names(DATA) %in% nm1], names(DATA)[names(DATA) %in% nm1])
lapply(lst1, function(x) setNames(x, sub("\\.\\d+$", "", names(x))))
```

---

Using OP's new example

```
r <- list( data.frame( AA = c(2,2,1,1,3,2), BB = c(1,1,1,2,2,NA), CC = 1:6), data.frame( AA = c(1,NA,3,1,3,2), BB = c(1,1,1,2,2,2)), data.frame( AA = c(1,NA,3,1,3,2), BB = c(1,1,1,2,2,2), DD = 0:5) )
DATA <- do.call(cbind, r)

tbl <- table(names(DATA))
nm1 <- names(which(tbl==max(tbl)))
lst1 <- split.default(DATA[names(DATA) %in% nm1], names(DATA)[names(DATA) %in% nm1])
lapply(lst1, function(x) setNames(x, sub("\\.\\d+$", "", names(x))))
#$AA
#  AA AA AA
#1  2  1  1
#2  2 NA NA
#3  1  3  3
#4  1  1  1
#5  3  3  3
#6  2  2  2

#$BB
#  BB BB BB
#1  1  1  1
#2  1  1  1
#3  1  1  1
#4  2  2  2
#5  2  2  2
#6 NA  2  2
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200487/discussion-on-answer-by-akrun-extracting-and-cbinding-similarly-named-variables).

Comment: Arun, [*my question there*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58309964/separate-columns-with-constant-numbers-and-condense-them-to-one-row-in-r-data-fr/58310137#58310137) is related to your answer here. Suppose we want to condense variables that are constant after the `lapply` call above. How can we do that here?