# Follow-up: Separate columns with constant numbers and condense them to one row in R data.frame

Tags: r, list, function, loops, dataframe

This question is a follow-up on [**my previous question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58309964/separate-columns-with-constant-numbers-and-condense-them-to-one-row-in-r-data-fr/58310137#58310137). In this question, after my `split.default()` call below, I get a *named* `list` of data.frames called `L`.

**Qs:** I was wondering how I could condense each data.frame in `L` whose each column consists of a constant number? (How about if I know the names of the data.frames whose columns are constant numbers?)

**My desired output** is shown further below.

```
r <- list(
   data.frame(study.name = rep("Jacob", 6), 
         X = c(2,2,1,1,NA, NA), 
         Y = c(1,1,1,2,1,NA), 
         A = rep(1, 6),
         B = rep(4, 6)), 

   data.frame(study.name = rep("Jon", 6), 
         X = c(1,NA,3,1,NA,NA), 
         G = c(1,1,1,2,NA,NA),
         A = rep(3, 6),
         B = rep(7, 6)))

DATA <- do.call(cbind, r)

nm1 <- Reduce(intersect, lapply(r, colnames))[-1] 
L <- split.default(DATA[names(DATA) %in% nm1], names(DATA)[names(DATA) %in% nm1])
```

## Desired output:

```
    # $A
    #   A A.1
    # 1 1   3

    # $B
    #   B B.1
    # 1 4   7

    # $X
    #    X X.1
    # 1  2   1
    # 2  2  NA
    # 3  1   3
    # 4  1   1
    # 5 NA  NA
    # 6 NA  NA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the `NA` rows should be preserved, apply `duplicated` by looping over the `list` as well as if all the elements of a particular are `NA`, then keep that row

```
lapply(L, function(x)  x[(rowSums(is.na(x)) == ncol(x))|!duplicated(x),])
#$A
#  A A.1
#1 1   3

#$B
#  B B.1
#1 4   7

#$X
#   X X.1
#1  2   1
#2  2  NA
#3  1   3
#4  1   1
#5 NA  NA
#6 NA  NA
```

---

If we also need a check for constant value

```
is_constant <- function(x) length(unique(x)) == 1L
lapply(L, function(x) if(all(sapply(x, is_constant))) x[1,, drop = FALSE] else x)
#$A
#  A A.1
#1 1   3

#$B
#  B B.1
#1 4   7

#$X
#   X X.1
#1  2   1
#2  2  NA
#3  1   3
#4  1   1
#5 NA  NA
#6 NA  NA
```

Comment: Hi Arun, [**HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58329836/splitting-data-frame-inside-and-outside-an-r-function) is my easy to follow question?