# Splitting data.frame inside and outside an R function

Tags: r, list, function, loops, dataframe

I have 3 data.frames ([**A**](https://github.com/izeh/m/blob/master/irr.csv),  **[B1](https://github.com/izeh/m/blob/master/irr2.csv)** and **[B2](https://github.com/izeh/m/blob/master/irr4.csv)**). I `split` each by variable `study.name` and get my **desired output** shown as `out1`, `out2`, `out3`:

```
J <- split(A, A$study.name);      out1 <- do.call(rbind, c(J, make.row.names = F))
M <- split(B1, B1$study.name);    out2 <- do.call(rbind, c(M, make.row.names = F))
N <- split(B2, B2$study.name);    out3 <- do.call(rbind, c(N, make.row.names = F))
```

But I'm wondering why I can't achieve the same output from my function `foo`? (see below)

```
 A <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/izeh/m/master/irr.csv", h = T)  ## data A
B1 <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/izeh/m/master/irr2.csv', h = T) ## data B1
B2 <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/izeh/m/master/irr4.csv", h = T) ## data B2

 foo <- function(...){      ## The unsuccessful function `foo`

    r <- list(...)

 ## r <- Can we HERE delete rows and columns that are ALL `NA` or EMPTY in `r`?

    J <- unlist(lapply(seq_along(r), function(i) split(r[[i]], r[[i]]$study.name)), recursive = FALSE)

    lapply(seq_along(J), function(i)do.call(rbind, c(J[[i]], make.row.names = FALSE)) )
}

foo(B1, B2) # Example without success
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do the cleaning of rows/columns before doing the `split`

```
foo <- function(...){  
    r <- list(...)

    lapply(r, function(dat) {

       m1 <- is.na(dat)|dat == ""
      i1 <- rowSums(m1) < ncol(m1)
      j1 <- colSums(m1) < nrow(m1)
      dat1 <- dat[i1, j1]
      facColumns <- sapply(dat1, is.factor)
      dat1[facColumns] <- lapply(dat1[facColumns], as.character)
      dat1$study.name <- factor(dat1$study.name, levels = unique(dat1$study.name))  
      l1 <- split(dat1, dat1$study.name)


          do.call(rbind, c(l1, make.row.names = FALSE))

     }

    )


}

lapply(foo(B1, B2), head, 2)
#[[1]]
#  study.name group.name outcome ESL prof scope type
#1 Shin.Ellis   ME.short       1   1    2     1    1
#2 Shin.Ellis    ME.long       1   1    2     1    1

#[[2]]
#  study.name group.name outcome ESL prof scope type
#1 Shin.Ellis   ME.short       1   1    2     1    1
#2 Shin.Ellis    ME.long       1   1    2     1    1
```

or using a single object as argument

```
lapply(foo(A), head, 2)
#[[1]]
#  study.name group.name outcome ESL prof scope type ESL.1 prof.1 scope.1 type.1
#1 Shin.Ellis   ME.short       1   1    2     1    1     1      2       1      1
#2 Shin.Ellis    ME.long       1   1    2     1    1     1      2       1      1
```

Comment: No problem, i fully understand. don't let this take you down. you're special! Also I think that [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58454100/repeat-a-subsetting-function-by-adding-a-new-subsetting-variable-at-each-round-i) is a bit different, I'll upvote you twice.